# Djnago Models Design Database

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-design, model

I am new to Django project and wanted to know what is the best practice for designing models.
I am working on creating a small project which will have collections of stories in a category and subcategorical manner. I am tagging it as Django because I wanted to also verify the scope of app.

Apps:
index, genre

Design:

```
Index

Genre
|-- Story
    |--Section
         |-- Chapters
             |--Paragraph
                 |-- title
                 |-- text
                 |-- highlights
```

genre.models.py

```
class Story(models.Model):
    stry = models.CharField(max_length=256,unique=True)
    id =models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.stry
class Section(models.Model):
    stry = models.ForeignKey(Story,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    desc=models.TextField()
    id =models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=240, null=True, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=False)    

class Chapter(models.Model):    
    sec = models.ForeignKey(Section,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    desc=models.TextField()
    id =models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=240, null=True, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=False)
class Paragraph(models.Model):
    chap = models.ForeignKey(Chapter,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=False)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=180, null=True, blank=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=240, null=True, blank=False)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=False)
```

The genre can have many stories, and each section can have many chapters and a similar pattern

Question:

- Is there a better design model that I can work on?
- Can divide these into different apps or have 1 app for each genre or
  include genre as a model.

Comment: What will do your `index`-app ?

Comment: @KlimBim index app is to be used as index. to show all the genre as a list and  allow search option to find a particular story. I was planning to make 1 app for each genre and use idex to show all list of apps. I am thinking that is a very bad idea

Comment: You can seperate it. However, you have to take care of your `namespace` when you want to use your `templates` or other things in a different app. For instance, if `app_name` is set in `urls.py`. If you are new at django, you can do it easily. Create different `path` for each purpose. For  instance, `path(genre/thriller/.......)`, `path(genre/comedy.....)` etc. and keep it in one app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose this kind of design.

```py
class DateTimeSlug(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    
class NameDesc(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    desc=models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Story(models.Model):
    stry = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.stry
    
class Section(DateTimeSlug, NameDesc):
    stry = models.ForeignKey(Story,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sections')
     
class Chapter(DateTimeSlug, NameDesc):    
    sec = models.ForeignKey(Section,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chapters')

class Paragraph(DateTimeSlug):
    chap = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='paragraphs')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=180)
    body = models.TextField()
```

`id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` is not necessary, because Django adds `id` with `AutoField`automatically. If you want to use a custom PrimaryKey, you have to make your own. I propose you can do it at `Story.stry`. Adding `blank=False, null=False` is not necessary. It is Django standard behavior.

If you want to use a model in yoru index-App, you can import it where you need it.

> Can divide these into different apps or have 1 app for each genre or include genre as a model.

In my opinion, I would add a kind of "genre-tag" at your `Story`-model and keep it all together.